# wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)); causes a WebDriverException: Failed to decode response from marionette

Tags: java, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

```
List<WebElement> itemList = getWebDriver().findElements(By.className("className"));
    WebElement target = null;
    for(WebElement e: itemList){
        if(e.getAttribute("textContent").equals("Stuff")){
            target = e;
        }
    }

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(target));
```

The wait line at the bottom is throwing an exception, and I would like to know why. This works:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("selector")));
```

But passing in a specific element instead of a By. path does not.

Comment: What is the exception?  Also, what version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: @BillHileman a WebDriverException. Tried to run a command without establishing a connection. But this happens in the middle of a test so I'm confused. Selenium 3.4 with Guava 21.0 and Firefox 53.03, along with version 0.16.1 of the gecko driver.

Comment: What are your versions of selenium, firefox and geckodriver? Sounds like an issue with the versions.

Comment: @mrfreester Please refer to my previous comment to Mr. Hileman. And I don't think so, that wouldn't really make sense as this only happens in a very specific case with very specific conditions.

Comment: @WallyMathaou sometimes specific functions will break when versions don't match, but other functionality will still work. But since at first glance it looks like you may be using the latest versions of everything, this may just be a bug that Mozilla needs to address with their driver not working with wait.until, or ExpectedConditions correctly.

Comment: [This may be relevant](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/how-to-use-geckodriver/). The important part: `Exception : Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to decode response from marionette (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information).

Solution : There is some mismatch between the Gecko version or Firefox version or Selenium version. First try updating the Gecko version from Github. If you still face the error try updating the FF version as well.
`

Comment: When you add additional information, please edit your question and add it there so the next reader doesn't have to read the question and all the comments to get all the relevant info.